# How fix a malformed entry in this apt file

Tags: files, source

Here is the error message:

```
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list (Component)
```

This is what's written in my file:

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 7):

The correct entry for the file should look something like this:

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu zesty main
```

where zesty should be replaced with the [codename of your ubuntu release version](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

The `$(lsb_release -sc)` is supposed to be a shell script command that would be expanded by the shell (e.g. bash) when you type something like this in the terminal:

```
echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
```

The shell command above are supposed to call the [lsb_release](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lsb_release) command to figure out the correct ubuntu codename (e.g. zesty for 17.04, yakkety for 16.10, xenial for 16.04). The output of lsb_release which should be the ubuntu release codename would then be interpolated into the string between the quotes and then written to the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list.

However, you must have put an extra space between `$` and `(` when typing the command, which causes the `$ (lsb_release -sc)` to be written literally, instead of having the output of the lsb_release command interpolated into the config file.